# Como inverter a ordem das colunas de um Dataframe com Python

Tags: python, data, estrutura-de-dados, pandas

Opa, gostaria de saber como posso inverter colunas inteiras com usando python.

```
FRUTA   |   VITAMINA   |   PREÇO
LARANJA |      C       |   2.00
MAÇÃ    |      B1      |   2.00
BANANA  |      B2      |   1.00
```

Gostaria de saber como poss transformar a coluna anterior nessa coluna de agora:

```
PREÇO   |   VITAMINA   |   FRUTA
2.00    |      C       |   LARANJA
2.00    |      B1      |   MAÇÃ
1.00    |      B2      |   BANANA
```

Quero apenas mudar a coluna inteira com todos os valores, como posso fazer isso? Grato =)

Answer (score 6):

Supondo que os nomes das colunas de seus DataFrame (DF) sejam "fruta", "vitamina" e "preço", nessa ordem. Você pode reordenar da seguinte forma:

```
df = df[['preço', 'vitamina', 'fruta']]
```

Ou seja, você precisa passar uma **lista** filtrando ou reordenando com os nomes de coluna que você precisa/deseja.

Comment: exatamente isso que eu queria! obrigado Leonardo!

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma bem genérica de inverter a ordem das colunas é selecionado as colunas de trás pra frente dentro do `loc`

```
df.loc[:,::-1]
```